# how to set a controller variable in a view from a form post

Tags: php, zend-framework, post, view, controller

I have a `Zend` view in `PHP` with a form:

```
<form action="https://example.com/checkout/" name="info" method="post"> 
    <div id="payment">
        <div id="paypal>
            <?php $this->is_paypal_payment = true; ?>
        </div>
        <div id="credit_card>
            <?php $this->is_paypal_payment = false; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

When a user clicks the submit button, how can I set the instance variable in the Controller?

This is what I tried which didn't work.

Controller:

```
$this->view->payment_option_paypal = false;  // initialized value

$payment_method_option = $this->_getParam('payment_option_paypal', null);
if (!is_null($payment_method_option)) {
   if ($payment_method_option == 'paypal') {
       $this->_is_paypal = true;
   }
}
```

View:

```
<div id="paypal" style="display: none;">
    <?php $this->payment_option_paypal = "paypal"; ?>
    <img src="paypal.gif" style="margin-right:20px;">
</div>
```

After clicking submit, `the _getParam()` function doesn't capture the string "paypal" that the view set for instance variable in Controller `$this->payment_option_paypal`

Any ideas what's wrong and how to go about this?

Comment: im not familiar with zend-framework but to pass values from view to controller works usually via input hidden fields (in case like you specified) or with normal html elements like checkboxes, textrea, select etc.. have you tried `<input type="hidden" name="payment_option_paypal" id="payment_option_paypal" value="true"/>` ?

Comment: you can use the _getParam for the input field or the for the hidden field so you are not get value of the div in this mathod

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in you **phtml page** you have to use like this

```
<div id="paypal" style="display: none;">
    <input type="hidden" name="paypalname" value="<?php echo $this->payment_option_paypal = "paypal"; ?>" id="paypalname"/>
    <img src="paypal.gif" style="margin-right:20px;">
</div>
```

and the **controller**

```
function yourAction()
{
      if ($this->_request->isPost()) 
      {
         $paypalvalue=$this->_getParam('paypalname');
      }
}
```

I hope it helps you and if you have any problem in my answer then let me know.

Answer (score 1):

a div will not submit data also anything that needs to be rendered as html must be echo'ed:

```
<form action="https://example.com/checkout/" name="info" method="post"> 
    <div id="payment">
        <div id="paypal>
            <?php echo $this->is_paypal_payment = true; ?><!-- maybe should be an input element of kind and echo the $this-> statement -->
        </div>
        <div id="credit_card>
            <?php echo $this->is_paypal_payment = false; ?><!-- maybe should be an input element of kind and echo the $this-> statement -->
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

again ECHO:

```
<div id="paypal" style="display: none;">
    <?php echo $this->payment_option_paypal = "paypal"; ?>
    <img src="paypal.gif" style="margin-right:20px;">
</div>
```